# Convert produced integers into a vertical list and reverse list order

Tags: python-3.5

This code converts decimal to binary, whilst still needing to be reversed to display the correct number.

```
dec = int(input("Please enter number to convert to decimal: "))   
while dec>0:
    quoteint = dec/2
    rem = dec%2
    print (int(rem))
    dec = int(dec/2)
```

I'm looking to get the numbers produced by the code below to be displayed in a line. Eg

```
1 0 0 1 0 0
```

But the code currently only produces the integers in a row like this.

```
1
0
0
1
0
0
```

I know I need to turn the integers into a list and then reverse the list to get it to display the correct binary number. Can someone explain how I could possibly do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think if you change the line

`print (int(rem))` to

`print (int(rem), end="")` that should do the job.

Comment: (i.e. include a comma AND end="")